# robumeta arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: r, meta

I'm trying to use robumeta and I keep running into an error. 
I'm using 113 observations on 8 variables:

```
EM <- read.csv(file="SchoolMotivationRisk.csv", header=TRUE,sep=",")
```

The eight variables are: studynum   yi  var.effect.size sei aget1   aget2   permale sexmix.

Doing str(EM) yields 'data.frame':  113 obs. of  8 variables.

The problem is when I go to fit:

```
res<-robu(formula = yi ~ 1, var.effect.size = var.effect.size, studynum = studynum, modelweights = "CORR", rho= 0.8, small=TRUE, data=EM)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(effect.size = mf[, 1], stats::model.matrix(formula,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 113, 0
```

Is there a way around this?

Also, the output from dput(EM) is at https://pastebin.com/vmMwy1u4

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example (with `dput`) that shows the error

Comment: Sure, if I do: 
     dput EM
I get this: https://pastebin.com/vmMwy1u4

Comment: Thanks for the dput.  The issue is with `var.eff.size`.

Comment: I'm receiving this error but using var.eff.size. Small number of obs in my sample, perhaps this is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter is `var.eff.size` and not `var.effect.size`

```
library(robumeta)
robu(formula = yi ~ 1, var.eff.size = var.effect.size, 
   studynum = studynum, modelweights = "CORR", rho= 0.8, small=TRUE, data=EM)
#RVE: Correlated Effects Model with Small-Sample Corrections 

#Model: yi ~ 1 

#Number of studies = 17 
#Number of outcomes = 113 (min = 2 , mean = 6.65 , median = 7 , max = 12 )
#Rho = 0.8 
#I.sq = 57.54005 
#Tau.sq = 0.004609755 

#               Estimate StdErr t-value dfs   P(|t|>) 95% CI.L 95% CI.U Sig
#1 X.Intercept.    0.113 0.0184    6.12  14 0.0000263   0.0733    0.152 ***
#---
#Signif. codes: < .01 *** < .05 ** < .10 *
#---
#Note: If df < 4, do not trust the results
```

Comment: ...oy. I messed up. Thanks!